# Image, Text and Buttons Side by side CSS

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS, and I want to achieve following in HTML or CSS, any help would be great.

[image]

Code I have

```
<div>
    <p>
        <img src="/dist/img/photos/featured-member-justine.jpg" height="50px" width="50px" /> <b>Influencer Name</b>
        <input type="button" value="Ignore" />
        <input type="button" value="Accept" />
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: it would be better if you show us your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this like:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div style="height:100px;">
                <div id='image' style="float:left;"><img src="" width="50px;" height="50px;"/></div>
                <div>
                    <div id='header' style="float:left;width=80%;" >
                        Influencer Name
                    </div><br/>
                    <div id='description' style="float:left;width=80%;">
                        Campaign: Campaign name lorem ipsum
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id='buttons' style="float:right;">
                    <input type="submit" value="Ignore" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Accept" />
                </div>
            </div>
             <div  style="height:100px;">
                <div id='image' style="float:left;"><img src="" width="50px;" height="50px;"/></div>
                <div>
                    <div id='header' style="float:left;width=80%;" >
                        Influencer Name
                    </div><br/>
                    <div id='description' style="float:left;width=80%;">
                        Campaign: Campaign name lorem ipsum
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id='buttons' style="float:right;">
                    <input type="submit" value="Ignore" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Accept" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, But If I add 2-3 Photos it is appearing like as follows [1]: http://s22.postimg.org/wtkhyzo3l/image.jpg

Comment: You are adding it at the wrong place. Add it to the parent div.

Comment: Still not working, can you please provide how to add multiple images ?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the answer for multiple images. Have a look please.